# NASM Assembly Integral Calculator

Tags: assembly, nasm, integral

I have to build a NASM assembler program that will take a definite integral of a to b using the trapezoidal rule with 1000 slices. For anyone who doesn't know what that is, it's b-a/2N * (f(x) + 2(f(x1) + 2(f(x2)) + ... + 2(f(xN)) + 2(f(xN+1)).

The function of f is sin(x) so every iteration must have the sin of (x + interval (interval is represented by 'n' in my code)) taken and multiplied by 2. I have to do this in a subroutine entirely without the use of special operators or functions. The main function only takes in values of the initial x value and the end x value and passes them to the subroutine. The subroutine returns a y value which is the sum of the function. I got it to work at least as far as taking the sine of x and multiplying it by 2 and storing that to add to the next sine of x, but eventually after like 30 or so iterations through the loop, it gives me NaN...

Here is my code so far for the subroutine:

```
.data

two             REAL8   2.0
half            REAL8   0.5 
x               REAL8   ?
n               REAL8   ?
i               dword   1000
thos            REAL8   1000.0
sum             REAL8   0.0
sum2            REAL8   ?
sum3            REAL8   ?

.code
integral1   PROC

PARAMS = 2*TYPE DWORD
NPARAMS = 3
x2$ = PARAMS+0*TYPE DWORD
x1$ = PARAMS+1*TYPE DWORD
y$  = PARAMS+2*TYPE DWORD

pushfd
;BELOW: Calculate interval
mov     ebx,x2$[esp]
fld     REAL8 PTR [ebx]

mov     ebx,x1$[esp]
fld     REAL8 PTR [ebx]
fsub
fdiv    thos
fstp    n

;BELOW: calculate 1/2 of interval per trapezoidal rule
fld     n
fld     half
fdiv
fstp    half
;BELOW: load 1000 into counter register and store x variable
mov     ecx,i
fld     REAL8 PTR [x1]
fstp    x
;BELOW: f(x) calculation
fld     REAL8 PTR [x]
fsin
fstp    sum2


for_loop:
fld     REAL8 PTR [x]
;load x onto stack
fld     REAL8 PTR [n]
;load interval onto stack
fadd
;add x and interval
fst     x
;store value in x for later use
fsin
;take sine of x
fmul    two
;multiply by 2 to get 2(f(x))
fst     sum3
;store value in arbitrary variable
fld     sum
;load current total of functions
fadd
;add sum3 to sum
fst     sum
;store sum and loop

cmp     ecx,0
je      end_for
dec     ecx
jmp     for_loop

end_for:
fld     REAL8 PTR [sum]
fmul    half
;multiply sum by 1/2
fadd    sum2
;add sine(x) to total before pushing back to main
mov     ebx,y$[esp]
fstp    REAL8 PTR [ebx]
popfd
ret NPARAMS*TYPE DWORD

integral1   ENDP

END main
```

If anyone could please help me understand why it is doing this or where my mistake is or how this can be corrected I would be forever grateful. I've been working on it for over 6 hours and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: You sure that this is NASM. Code seems to be MASM?

Comment: x87 is essentially obsolete, except for 80bit precision when 64bit double isn't enough.  If you're using 64bit temporaries, you're losing out on the only benefit x87 has over SSE/SSE2.  (Also note that the `fsin` instruction is slower and less accurate than good math library `sin` implementations.  I think the accuracy is [only a problem when the input lies far outside the `-pi..pi` range](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/289702), though.  See the discussion on that thread for how many ULP of error you can expect)

Comment: I [found an interesting plot showing where fcos has more than 1ulp of error](http://notabs.org/fpuaccuracy/), which happens even for small arguments that don't need range-reduction.  By comparison, FP mul/add/sub results are always accurate to 0.5 ulp (i.e. correctly rounded).  I think glibc's libm implementation aims for that level of accuracy in math functions.  This may or may not matter to you.  I assume you're doing this as an asm-learning exercise, because C would be much easier.

Comment: In the realm of questions not asked, this is NASM assembler with the Irvine library. And I didn't ask about accuracy, that isn't an issue in this program as I have to calculate the absolute and relative error on paper.

Comment: NASM doesn't use the syntax you are using. Are you sure you aren't confusing this with MASM? (Microsoft Assembler). NASM doesn't use REAL8 (or REAL4), it doesn't understand `.code` and `.data` directives and doesn't support the `ptr` modifier on memory operands. However, all these things do work with **M**ASM

Comment: Doesn't matter anymore. It is NASM and I completed it myself.